# Erlang hex string to ascii string

Tags: erlang, hex, ascii

I have a problem with converting hex string to ascii string in erlang.

Example:

My string :`45474D31303930303031`

Desired value parsed : `EGM1090001`

What's the best approach for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rather create function for such conversion. Kind of:

```
hex2s(HStr) -> hex2s(HStr,[]).

hex2s([X1,X2|Rest], Acc) ->  hex2s(Rest, [ hv(X1) * 16 + hv(X2) |Acc ]);
hex2s([], Acc)           -> lists:reverse(Acc).

hv($0) -> 0;
hv($1) -> 1; 
hv($2) -> 2;
hv($3) -> 3; 
hv($4) -> 4; 
hv($5) -> 5; 
hv($6) -> 6; 
hv($7) -> 7; 
hv($8) -> 8; 
hv($9) -> 9; 
hv($A) -> 10; 
hv($B) -> 11; 
hv($C) -> 12;
hv($D) -> 13; 
hv($E) -> 14; 
hv($F) -> 15.
```

testing:

hex2s("45474D31303930303031").

"EGM1090001"

Comment: Hi, i found a default command for hex to char conversion '{ok, [NewChar], _} = io_lib:fread("~16u", [X1]++[X2])'  Hope helps in future!

Comment: yes, I am aware of io_lib:fread, but for my opinion it is too heavy to use it for this task..

Comment: I agree `io_lib` is too heavy for this. But the posted solution here doesn't need all the `hv/1` clauses either. Rather, the first `hex2s/2` clause can just call `list_to_integer([X1,X2], 16)` in place of the calls to `hv/1` and associated arithmetic. It's just as fast and is much less code.